# Adding local jars to sbt classpath fails with MalformedURLException: no protocol

Tags: scala, sbt, classpath

I am using Scala version 2.10 and SBT version 0.13.8. In my Intellij project I need to compile a program that depends on external jars. I have added `libraryDependencies` and `resolvers` in the below format

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

resolvers += "Local IE Libraries" at "E/Temp/IE"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.gigaspaces.insightedge" % "insightedge-core" % "1.0.0")
```

I get an error

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.gigaspaces.insightedge#insightedge-core;1.0.0: Local InsightEdge Libraries: unable to get resource for org/gigaspaces/insightedge#insightedge-core;1.0.0: res=E/Temp/IE/org
e/insightedge-core/1.0.0/insightedge-core-1.0.0.pom: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: E/Temp/IE/org/gigaspaces/insightedge/insightedge-core/1.0.0/insightedge-core-1.0.0.pom
```

**Update**

If I specify the resolver path with a `file://` prefix as

```
resolvers += "Local InsightEdge Libraries" at "file://E/Temp/IE"
```

I get a different error

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.gigaspaces.insightedge#insightedge-core;1.0.0: URI has an authority component
```

Is the problem due to the windows path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line

```
resolvers += "Local IE Libraries" at "E/Temp/IE"
```

which results then in the URL the `MalformedURLException` is complaining about

```
E/Temp/IE/org/gigaspaces/insightedge/insightedge-core/1.0.0/insightedge-core-1.0.0.pom
```

More specifically the exception says "no protocol". So you might want to prepend a "file://" if this is a local repository. Not sure if relative paths work, but providing an absolute path should work:

```
file://absolute/path/to/the/directory/against/which/to/resolve
```

This Wikipedia page might help you to figure out how to specify the path on your Windwows system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Windows

Comment: I had already tried file protocol but I get a different error. I have updated the description with more details. Let me know if you have more suggestions

Comment: Where on your systems is the directory? Which drive? Complete path? If E is the drive then you should specify it according to the format in the link in my answer.

Comment: I tried all the paths from the link. Though none of them worked, the errors were different. I think we are close to the solution. Kindly have a look at the details here - http://pastebin.com/WwpfJtSS. Let me know your inputs.

Comment: Have you tried without the localhost part? "file://e:/Temp/IE" or file:///e:/Temp/IE"?

Comment: Yes. Both of them fail with one of the errors listed above - http://pastebin.com/MyuT7isb

Comment: Well, the second error ("org.gigaspaces.insightedge#insightedge-core;1.0.0: not found") says that the URI format is ok, but it doesn't find the dependency there. Did you try pasting the URI in the address bar of your browser to check if it is correct? Maybe it is a casing problem (E: instead of e:?). Just guessing here. Also check the contents of the directory. Is the version the same that you are requiring (insightedge-core-1.0.0.pom)? Can you send me the list of directory contents in Temp/IE?

Comment: In the directory I have the jar named "insightedge-core-1.0.0.jar" which has the pom properties file under META-INF directory. I verified the case problem (E: instead of e:) but I get the same error. Does the jar name and its packaging needs to be different for scala to find it?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I think it is possible that you need a certain directory structure within the folder you are referring to. Maybe you have to place the jar insight a folder "insightedge-core/1.0.0" or something like that. Or "org/gigaspaces/insightedge", or "org.gigaspaces.insightedge". Again, rather guessing here, but that's what I would try.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html Search for the section "Explicit URL". At least that should work.

Comment: Yes. Explicit url works well. This also certifies that the jar name or the jar file structure isn't a problem. Any ideas on what could be wrong with the local folder resolver given explicit url works fine? Appreciate your time and effort on this. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that explicitly providing the jar name works does not certify that it is named correctly or is located in the right place. It just shows the jar is working once it is found. In order to be found it has to be in a place the resolver checks (without explicitly giving it the location). Did you try putting it into different folders as I suggested above?